# Fluent Validation - One of n items has to be set

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a class called 'CustomerDataContract' wich has three attributes: MobilePhone, OfficePhone and PrivatePhone. In order to get in touch with the customer at least one of the attributes has to be set.

I created a Validator-Class and added a custom rule called 'CheckForAnyPhoneNumber' to check wheter or not at least one phone number has been provided. This almost solves my problem. The only problem I have is, that if I clear for example the MobilePhone-Attribute it gets evaluated and is in error state. If I now enter a OfficePhone number, the MobilePhone-Attribute does not get reevaluated and stays in error-mode.

Any idea how to solve this problem correctly? I also tried creating a RuleSet but without success.

Here's the (partial) CustomerDataContract:

```
public partial class CustomerDataContract
{

    public CustomerDataContract Clone()
    {
        return (CustomerDataContract) MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public override ValidationResult SelfValidate()
    {
        return ValidationHelper.Validate<CustomerDataContractValidator, CustomerDataContract>(this);
    }

}
```

The Base Class of all DataContracts:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class BDataModel : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    [field: NonSerialized]
    private ValidationResult _currentState = new ValidationResult();

    public ValidationResult CurrentValidationState
    {
        get { return _currentState; }
        set 
        { 
            _currentState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentValidationState");
            OnPropertyChanged("IsValid");
            OnPropertyChanged("Error");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] propertyName)
    {
        propertyName.ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(x));
        });
    }

    #endregion

    public virtual ValidationResult SelfValidate()
    {
        return new ValidationResult();
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurrentValidationState == null)
                CurrentValidationState = SelfValidate();
            return CurrentValidationState.IsValid;
        }
    }

    #region IDataErrorInfo

    public string Error
    {
        get { return ValidationHelper.GetError(CurrentValidationState); }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            CurrentValidationState = SelfValidate();
            if (_currentState == null) return string.Empty;
            var columnResults = _currentState.Errors.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.PropertyName, columnName, true) == 0);
            return columnResults != null ? columnResults.ErrorMessage : string.Empty;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Here's the Validator class:

```
public class CustomerDataContractValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerDataContract>
{
    private readonly ILanguageManager _languageManager = LanguageManager.Instance;

    public CustomerDataContractValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(val => val.Lastname).NotEmpty().WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideLastname"]);
        RuleFor(val => val.Firstname).NotEmpty().WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideFirstname"]);
        RuleFor(val => val.Active).NotEmpty().WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideActive"]);
        RuleFor(val => val.Gender).NotEmpty().WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideGender"]);
        RuleFor(val => val.Mail).EmailAddress().When(val => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Mail)).WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideValidEmail"]);

        // At least one phone number has to be filled in order to contact the customer
        RuleFor(val => val.MobilePhone).Must(CheckForAnyPhoneNumber).WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideAnyPhone"]);
        RuleFor(val => val.OfficePhone).Must(CheckForAnyPhoneNumber).WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideAnyPhone"]);
        RuleFor(val => val.PrivatePhone).Must(CheckForAnyPhoneNumber).WithMessage(_languageManager.LanguageData["Global.Validation.ProvideAnyPhone"]);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks wheter or not any phone number has been provided
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="customer">The customer</param>
    /// <param name="phoneNumber">The phone number</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool CheckForAnyPhoneNumber(CustomerDataContract customer, string phoneNumber)
    {
        return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.MobilePhone) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.OfficePhone) || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.PrivatePhone));
    }
}
```

And the Validation Helper:

```
public class ValidationHelper
{
    public static ValidationResult Validate<T, K>(K entity)
        where T : IValidator<K>, new()
        where K : class
    {
        IValidator<K> validator = new T();
        return validator.Validate(entity);
    }

    public static string GetError(ValidationResult result)
    {
        var errorMessage = "";
        if (result != null)
        {
            var failure = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
            if(failure != null)
            {
                errorMessage = failure.ErrorMessage;
            }
        }
        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : BMovingSelectionViewModel, IEventListener, ICustomerViewModel
{

    private CustomerDataContract _customer;

    public CustomerDataContract Customer
    {
        get
        {
            return _customer;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_customer != value)
            {
                _customer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Customer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<TextBlock Text="{MarkupExtensions:LanguageManager Global.Person.PhoneOffice}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Validation:ValidationBinding Path=Customer.OfficePhone}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  />

<TextBlock Text="{MarkupExtensions:LanguageManager Global.Person.PhonePrivate}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Validation:ValidationBinding Path=Customer.PrivatePhone}" />

<TextBlock Text="{MarkupExtensions:LanguageManager Global.Person.PhoneMobile}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Validation:ValidationBinding Path=Customer.MobilePhone}" />
```

Comment: @minhcat_vo: WPF with MVVM

Comment: @Silvan: Last time I checked, FluentValidation didn't have a direct integration into WPF with MVVM, meaning you had to call the validator yourself. Is this still the case? If so, how / where do you execute the validator?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Correct. I have a base class for all DataContracts which implements IDataErrorInfo and the binding is configured to reevaluate an attribute on each PropertyChanged Event. So whenever I change an attribute, it gets reevaluated (but not the 'depending' attributes).

Comment: @Silvan: Could you please reproduce the relevant parts of this base class in your question? I have a rough idea how I would solve your problem - the base class would help me in doing so.

Comment: @Silvan: Thanks. So, if I understand the code correctly, you don't actually perform the validation in response to a property changed even. Rather you perform the validation in the indexer of `IDataErrorInfo`, so basically, you validate every time the WPF infrastructure asks for the error of a property. Is that correct? And what is `CustomerDataContract`? Is this supposed to be the ViewModel?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: That's correct. The CustomerDataContract is a DataContract class from a WCF-Service. In my ViewModel I have a property called Customer which is of type CustomerDataContract. In the View I bind to the attributes of the Customer property. I'll extend my post.

Comment: @Silvan: Would it be an option to simply raise a property changed for each dependent property in the property setter? E.g. `public string PhonePrivate { get {...} set { ... OnPropertyChanged("PhonePrivate", "PhoneMobile", "PhoneOffice"); } }` That should re-evaluate the bindings and update the error info in the UI.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The setter are generated automaticaly and are regenerated each time the service reference get's updated. I could create some wrapper properties in my partial class i.e. MobilePhoneWrapper and raise OnPropertyChanged as you suggested. This would work. However that's more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: @Silvan: Does that mean that setting a property on the `CustomerDataContract` doesn't even raise a `PropertyChanged` for that specific property?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: It raises PropertyChanged! We wrote a VS Plugin that extends the 'Add Service Reference' functionality and adds the OnPropertyChanged method automatically on all properties (and other stuff).

Comment: @Silvan: Ah, very nice! In that case, please check the second solution in my answer. If you need more information than that sketch, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make WPF update the error info it needs to be triggered to do so. That trigger is a `PropertyChanged` event on the bound property.

---

The simplest solution would be to involve your view model. If you can do this, you simply need to raise `PropertyChanged` events for all dependent properties in the setter of each property in the group of dependent properties.
That means that setting `PhoneOffice` would raise a `PropertyChanged` for `"PhoneOffice"`, `"PhonePrivate"` and for `"PhoneMobile"`.

---

Another solution would be to work with rule sets and put the relevant code into the base class. To make it work, the following steps would need to be performed:

1. Make the base class listen to its own `PropertyChanged` event
2. In the event handler, get the validation rule for this property
3. Get all other validation rules for the same rule set
4. Raise `PropertyChanged` for the properties of the validation rules

Comment: I solved my problem by generating an Interface which holds a dependency dictionary. In the OnPropertyChanged method of my BDataModel base class I now check if the current class implements this interface, if so, get the dependencies of the current property and raise OnPropertyChanged for the depenencies. With this solution I endup with something similar to your first solution! Thx for the fantastic help!

Comment: This may work, but does not address the base question which is how I write a fluent validator that ensures one of the fields in the object has a value. I am using fluent validation with WebAPI to validate my requests so don't have option of a view model. This seems to be basic functionality to me.